# Should I submit something to YQL without first encoding it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql

If I'm sending a query like:

```
$.getScript('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html ' + 
    'where url="..."&callback=cb')
```

Is it safe to send it without encoding it or should I encode it someway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it? I haven't tried `getScript()`, just a simple `get()` instead, but it works for me in FF4.0.1 and Chrome 11.

However, I would still recommending using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the query string to avoid being dependent on browser behaviour:

```
$.getScript('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="..."') + '&callback=cb');
```